# Firebase create new audience not responding

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

Hello I am creating a new Audience in Firebase console for a game (already released on store with roughly 17k DAU). However, the tool keep becoming not responding. I checked it seems to be a problem with Firebase's JS. More details below:

Error in Chrome developer debug:

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

Screenshot: Firebase Javascript error

[image]

I tried changing the date range to 7 days, yesterday, today. Same error.

Is there a way to workaround this issue? Thank you

Comment: Since this question is not about code you wrote, I doubt most developers here can help with it. Instead I'd recommend [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I will try to get in touch with them.